# grep with wild card character in shell variable

Tags: shell, grep, ksh

I have to use grep command in ksh script in the following way.
I have a shell variable `$string` which will have random string parameter each time and I want to find it partial match using regular expression "*"

I have tried:

1. `grep "$string" file.txt` => not fetching partially
2. `grep "$string*" file.txt` => it gives result 0 or more occurrences at the end of the string
3. now I want to use `grep "*$string*" file.txt` ..I have escaped it `"\*$string*"` or `"*\$string*"` does not help me ?

How to use `grep "*$string*" file.txt`? Or any other commands?

I have input for `$string="AAA"` and the output should match

1. `AAA`, or
2. `<any number of characters>AAA<any number of characters>`

If `AAA` is found anywhere it should match ..generally grep will do that but its not fetching here.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show us a sample of your input, your `$string` variable and the expected output.

Comment: If your string is `AAA`, then `grep "$string" file.txt` should return all lines containing `AAA`. You should probably use the `-F` switch too, to match fixed strings but it should work without. Show us some input and desired output so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not clear from your question, I suspect that you are looking for the `-F` flag for fixed strings. This makes sure that there are no regex meta characters.

Comment: note :

I have input for $string="AAA" and the output should match 1.AAA OR 2.AAA

if AAA is found anywhere it should match ..generally grep will do that but its not fetching here

Answer (score 1):

To search strings is better to use fgrep or the equivalent grep -F

> -F, --fixed-strings
>   Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

The following example should match all occurrence of "$string" in file.

```
fgrep "$string" file.txt
```